# Можно ли в Animator уменьшить прямоугольники с названиями?

Tags: unity3d

В Аниматоре названия анимаций располагаются в прямоугольниках, которые можно двигать, соединять анимации между собой.
На изображении они все справа:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот. У меня много анимаций.  Названия могут быть небольшими. Хотелось бы покомпактнее их расположить.
Можно ли эти прямоугольники сделать каждый произвольного размера? Или в Юнити это вшито и никак не изменить без хирургического вмешательства?

Использую версию 5.0.0.f4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне известно - никак. Если перевести проект в текстовый режим с помощью `Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor -> Asset Serialiation -> Mode -> Force Text`, затем открыть папку, где сохранен `Animator Controller`и открыть его текстовым редактором, то мы увидим что-то такое:

```
%YAML 1.1
%TAG !u! tag:unity3d.com,2011:
--- !u!91 &9100000
AnimatorController:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  m_Name: ct
  serializedVersion: 5
  m_AnimatorParameters: []
  m_AnimatorLayers:
  - serializedVersion: 5
    m_Name: Base Layer
    m_StateMachine: {fileID: 110785748}
    m_Mask: {fileID: 0}
    m_Motions: []
    m_Behaviours: []
    m_BlendingMode: 0
    m_SyncedLayerIndex: -1
    m_DefaultWeight: 0
    m_IKPass: 0
    m_SyncedLayerAffectsTiming: 0
    m_Controller: {fileID: 9100000}
--- !u!1102 &110213556
AnimatorState:
  serializedVersion: 5
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 1
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  m_Name: New State
  m_Speed: 1
  m_CycleOffset: 0
  m_Transitions: []
  m_StateMachineBehaviours: []
  m_Position: {x: 50, y: 50, z: 0}
  m_IKOnFeet: 0
  m_WriteDefaultValues: 1
  m_Mirror: 0
  m_SpeedParameterActive: 0
  m_MirrorParameterActive: 0
  m_CycleOffsetParameterActive: 0
  m_Motion: {fileID: 0}
  m_Tag: 
  m_SpeedParameter: 
  m_MirrorParameter: 
  m_CycleOffsetParameter: 
--- !u!1102 &110228362
AnimatorState:
  serializedVersion: 5
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 1
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  m_Name: New State 0
  m_Speed: 1
  m_CycleOffset: 0
  m_Transitions: []
  m_StateMachineBehaviours: []
  m_Position: {x: 50, y: 50, z: 0}
  m_IKOnFeet: 0
  m_WriteDefaultValues: 1
  m_Mirror: 0
  m_SpeedParameterActive: 0
  m_MirrorParameterActive: 0
  m_CycleOffsetParameterActive: 0
  m_Motion: {fileID: 0}
  m_Tag: 
  m_SpeedParameter: 
  m_MirrorParameter: 
  m_CycleOffsetParameter: 
--- !u!1107 &110785748
AnimatorStateMachine:
  serializedVersion: 5
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 1
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  m_Name: Base Layer
  m_ChildStates:
  - serializedVersion: 1
    m_State: {fileID: 110213556}
    m_Position: {x: 456, y: 12, z: 0}
  - serializedVersion: 1
    m_State: {fileID: 110228362}
    m_Position: {x: 288, y: -72, z: 0}
  m_ChildStateMachines: []
  m_AnyStateTransitions: []
  m_EntryTransitions: []
  m_StateMachineTransitions: {}
  m_StateMachineBehaviours: []
  m_AnyStatePosition: {x: 50, y: 20, z: 0}
  m_EntryPosition: {x: 50, y: 120, z: 0}
  m_ExitPosition: {x: 800, y: 120, z: 0}
  m_ParentStateMachinePosition: {x: 800, y: 20, z: 0}
  m_DefaultState: {fileID: 110213556}
```

Как можно заметить, в файле нет ни слова про размер плашки состояния, только ее позиция (`m_Position`). То есть, размер, скорее всего, жестко задан где-то в коде или конфигах самого Unity.

Возможно, для упорядочивания большого количества анимаций имеет смысл воспользоваться [вложенными стейт машинами](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NestedStateMachines.html).

Comment: Слои немного для другой цели служат. Как более правильный вариант будет использование sub-state machine, я думаю.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да, спасибо. Я, в общем-то, их и имел в виду, просто перепутал со слоями. Подправил ответ.

Comment: Дополню тут.
Действительно, похоже, такой возможности (изменять размер планки) и не будет. Никто не жаловался пока что на это. Надо написать им чтоб внедрили такую возможность =)
Выход пока `sub-state machine`. Для группировки, к примеру "`удар рукой вверх|удар рукой вбок|удар рукой вниз|удар рукой по лбу`" и т.д...
Для интересующихся о саб стейт машине можно посмотреть  [ТУТ](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpekqN4_4xg)

Answer (score 0):

Управляйте масштабом окна редактора. Сами свойства не увеличиваются.